# How do I find the power absorbed from the current sources without voltage sources?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: circuit]

Given this circuit, how do I determine the power absorbed from the dependent current sources? I figured out, through KCL, that \$R_{\text{a}} = 4/3 \Omega\$, \$R_{\text{b}} = 6 \Omega\$, \$R_{\text{c}} = 24/7 \Omega\$.

What I'm most confused about is given that P = IV, how can I figure out the voltage of each current source?

Comment: Are you aware of the superposition method, where you turn off all sources but one, note down the currents and voltages across each element, do that for all sources, and then add up the results?

Comment: im afraid im not familiar with that

Comment: Congratulations, Now you are.

Comment: i didn't understand how it works

Comment: We don't handout homework/quiz solutions here. You need to demonstrate that you have tried to solve this yourself. Show us **all** of your work. Then ask a **specific** question.

Comment: You don't need P=IV to solve this question. You are given all the voltages on the circuit. Keep trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your numbers for the resistances are all incorrect. Try again.

Secondly, the power is just voltage * current. Use KVL to find the voltage across each current source. For example, the 3A source has 12V + 4V  =  16V. The power is thus 48W.

You must pay attention to the polarity. In this case it is 48W produced by the current source. If the voltage was in the opposite direction relative to the current direction the power would be absorbed by the current source.

Comment: Hi! What did you do to calculate the resistances?

Comment: I did it pretty much by inspection. You can apply KCL, find the currents in each branch and find the resistances from the current and voltage drop between nodes.

Comment: Correct me if im wrong, to solve for the current of Ra, I have 3A - 2A = 1A, Ra = 4V/1A = 4 ohms?

Comment: Yes, you have it.

Comment: Hi again, it seemed i got stuck. when computing for Rb = Vb/ Ib = -3V/(2A+(-1.5A)), in which i got negative resistance. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The current is going into the (-) side of the resistor as marked, so take it as negative.

Comment: I see, makes sense. Thanks !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120814/discussion-between-aeden-schmidt-and-spehro-pefhany).